# Getting Form mouse coordinated on PictureBox on mouse click override - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, mouseclick-event

I'm drawing a MyPictureBox which inherits from PictureBox, and i override it's `OnMouseClick`
I set the arguments to be :`(MouseEventArgs e)` so i get the mouse coordinated when clicked,
The problem is the coordinates are the `MyPictureBox` relative coordinates while i need the coordinated from the `Form`.

How can it be done ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try the [Control.PointToClient Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx)?

Comment: It would've helped if i get the Screen Coordinated, but i get the PictureBox relative coordinates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First map the passed mouse coordinate to the screen.  Then map it back to the client coordinates of the form.  So the typical code would look like this, spelled out for clarity:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var pbox = (PictureBox)sender;
        var form = this;
        var screenPos = pbox.PointToScreen(e.Location);
        var formPos = form.PointToClient(screenPos);
        // etc..
    }
```

Or the short version:

```
    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        var formPos = this.PointToClient(pictureBox1.PointToScreen(e.Location));
        // etc..
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using

```
this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

this will get the position of your mouse cursor relative to your form.